# (Arena) How do I turn off highlighting of occupied squares under attack?

Tags: arena

It seem to follow some scheme showing what is under attach and if it is a good trade. Specifially I don't want the red/green/yellow highlighting in the image below.

This is v1.1 for Linux.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Care to explain the down vote?

Comment: I did not down vote, but some people could argue that this question is not related to chess (but how to use a computer application) and therefore not within scope.

Comment: Saw quite a few Arena questions here. And those were the first that came up in google as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the "help" tab there is a "show attacked pieces" option which removes the color coding.

Comment: Thanks! I looked and relooked in options->appearance and didn't look under help.